# Random network plot setting in R

Tags: r, networking, plot, igraph

I generated a random network by using 620 nodes and 2102 edges. I want to visualize it by using plot.But, 1. not sure how to make the plot nicer (make nodes more separated at least)? 2.adjust the node size based on 'degree'.
my codes are:

```
set.seed(42)
Network_random <- erdos.renyi.game(620,2102,type='gnm')
plot(Network_random, vertex.col="degree", main="Network Random",layout=layout_nicely,margin=-0.25)
```

my current plot is as below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
set.seed(42)
Network_random <- erdos.renyi.game(620, 2102, type = "gnm") %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "size", value = pmax(degree(.), 5)) %>%
  plot(vertex.label = NA, vertex.color = degree(.), main = "Network Random", margin = -0.25)
```

[image]